# Link the FAQ's entries on privileges with the respective entries

Tags: feature-request, privileges, site-faq

With FAQ I mean the sites own FAQ, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/faq.

"What does close a question mean" can then be directly answered by a click instead of a search.

Comment: I'm confused; which page do you want this link to be on, and which page do you want it to point to?

Comment: @Popular Looks like linking the entries in the `site/faq` page for the reputation abilities with the corresponding entries of the `privileges` page. That way, people go immediately to the corresponding ability when reading the FAQ for the first time.

Comment: @Grace, that's what I suspected, but I wasn't 100% sure. We really have far too many things called "the FAQ."

Comment: @pop sorry for the confusion, yes, what @grace said (I want multi@replies...)